# Deploy on openshift with a tomcat 7 server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, openshift

We have a Java web project. We run it on a tomcat7 server. However, we want to deploy our application to openshift.

When we opened the eclipse plugin we did not find any tomcat 7 server. Therefore we tried to install everything by the console. However, that is an endless amount of work!

Is there an easy way to deploy out project to openshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for pointing this out. You're right, the Eclipse tooling is not as verbose as it could be. We'll have to improve it. The web ui does a far better job and unveils that tomcat 7 is equivalent to jbossews-2.0.

[image: web ui]

So if you want to use tomcat7 while using the Eclipse plugin you'll have to select jbossews-2.0:

[image: jboss tools]

Answer (score 0):

We added nicer labels in the upcoming version of JBoss Tools 4.1.o Beta1:

[image]

You can get more details about it in the issue in our JIRA: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-14459

4.1.0. Beta1 should get out in the end of may.